# jquery update value of input field by selecting an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Two input fields and one select field are being added dynamically by jquery. It should update the value of a selected option in the field named "hidden_name". It works with static fields, but it does not work as expected:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\" />");
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" name=\"values[]\" />");
        var fType = $("<select name=\"values\" class=\"extra_tab_list fieldtype\"> <optgroup label=\"Social Items\"><option value=\"fa-adn\" data-icon=\"fa-adn\">Adn</option> <option value=\"fa-android\" data-icon=\"fa-android\">Android</option> <option value=\"fa-apple\" data-icon=\"fa-apple\">Apple</option> <option value=\"fa-bitbucket\" data-icon=\"fa-bitbucket\">Bitbucket</option> <option value=\"fa-bitbucket-square\" data-icon=\"fa-bitbucket-square\">Bitbucket</option> <option value=\"fa-bitcoin\" data-icon=\"fa-bitcoin\">Bitcoin</option> <option value=\"fa-btc\" data-icon=\"fa-btc\">Btc</option> <option value=\"fa-css3\" data-icon=\"fa-css3\">Css3</option> <option value=\"fa-dribbble\" data-icon=\"fa-dribbble\">Dribbble</option> <option value=\"fa-dropbox\" data-icon=\"fa-dropbox\">Dropbox</option> <option value=\"fa-facebook-square\" data-icon=\"fa-facebook-square\">Facebook</option> <option value=\"fa-flickr\" data-icon=\"fa-flickr\">Flickr</option> <option value=\"fa-foursquare\" data-icon=\"fa-foursquare\">Foursquare</option> <option value=\"fa-github-square\" data-icon=\"fa-github-square\">Github</option> <option value=\"fa-gittip\" data-icon=\"fa-gittip\">Gittip</option> <option value=\"fa-google-plus-square\" data-icon=\"fa-google-plus-square\">Google Plus</option> <option value=\"fa-html5\" data-icon=\"fa-html5\">Html5</option> <option value=\"fa-instagram\" data-icon=\"fa-instagram\">Instagram</option> <option value=\"fa-linkedin-square\" data-icon=\"fa-linkedin-square\">Linkedin</option> <option value=\"fa-linux\" data-icon=\"fa-linux\">Linux</option> <option value=\"fa-maxcdn\" data-icon=\"fa-maxcdn\">Maxcdn</option> <option value=\"fa-pagelines\" data-icon=\"fa-pagelines\">Pagelines</option> <option value=\"fa-pinterest-square\" data-icon=\"fa-pinterest-square\">Pinterest</option> <option value=\"fa-renren\" data-icon=\"fa-renren\">Renren</option> <option value=\"fa-skype\" data-icon=\"fa-skype\">Skype</option> <option value=\"fa-stack-exchange\" data-icon=\"fa-stack-exchange\">Stack Exchange</option> <option value=\"fa-stack-overflow\" data-icon=\"fa-stack-overflow\">Stack Overflow</option> <option value=\"fa-trello\" data-icon=\"fa-trello\">Trello</option> <option value=\"fa-tumblr-square\" data-icon=\"fa-tumblr-square\">Tumblr</option> <option value=\"fa-twitter-square\" data-icon=\"fa-twitter-square\">Twitter</option> <option value=\"fa-vimeo-square\" data-icon=\"fa-vimeo-square\">Vimeo</option> <option value=\"fa-vk\" data-icon=\"fa-vk\">Vk</option> <option value=\"fa-waze\" data-icon=\"fa-waze\">Waze</option> <option value=\"fa-weibo\" data-icon=\"fa-weibo\">Weibo</option> <option value=\"fa-windows\" data-icon=\"fa-windows\">Windows</option> <option value=\"fa-xing-square\" data-icon=\"fa-xing-square\">Xing</option> <option value=\"fa-youtube-play\" data-icon=\"fa-youtube-play\">Youtube</option></optgroup><optgroup label=\"Misc\"><option value=\"fa-envelope\" data-icon=\"fa-envelope\">Email</option><option value=\"fa-phone-square\" data-icon=\"fa-phone-square\">Contact</option><option value=\"fa-address-card\" data-icon=\"fa-address-card\">Address</option><option value=\"fa-star\" data-icon=\"fa-star\">Custom</option></optgroup></select><input type=\"text\" class=\"hidden_name\" placeholder=\"Selected Value Will be Here\" name=\"hidden_values[]\" />");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });


    $('.extra_tab_list').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('.fieldwrapper').find('.hidden_name').val($('option:selected', this).data('icon'));
    });



});
```

The working example can be seen here;
[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zubairmushtaq/6m3bLfry/7/)

Comment: Code is working just move change function inside click function.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements you must use `.on( "event", handler )` instead of attach event directly, so change the code to:

```
    $(document).on('change','.extra_tab_list',function() {
        $(this).closest('.fieldwrapper').find('.hidden_name').val($('option:selected', this).data('icon'));
     });
```

and it should work.

for more details about the difference between .on('event') vs .event() check this link: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: Thanks, this solution is also working for me. Thanks a lot, Brother Mostafa.

Answer (score 0):

use delegation model

html--

```
 <select name="hello" id="txtSelect">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    Value:<input type="text" val="" id="selectedValOpt"/>
```

js --

```
$(document).on('change','#txtSelect',function(event){
    var selected = $('#txtSelect').val();
    $('#selectedValOpt').val(selected);
    console.log(selected)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, Sagar! I have got the solution. Thank you very much.